# What is wrong with my Spring and Hibernate configuration?

Tags: xml, hibernate, spring, hibernate3

What is wrong with this configuration?  I'm using Spring 3 and Hibernate 3.6 and trying to set up to use DAOs.  I'm seeing two errors in hibernate.cfg.xml.

The first is on the session-factory tag-

```
 The content of element type "session-factory" must match 
"(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)".
```

The second is on the - property name="dataSource" - tag-

```
The content of element type "property" must match "null".
```

application-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
      </property>
      <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/projectName</value>
      </property>
      <property name="username">
        <value>uname</value>
      </property>
      <property name="password">
        <value>pass</value>
      </property>
      <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
       <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
    </property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">
    thread
    </property>
    <mapping class="com.projectname.model.name"/>
    <mapping class="com.projectname.model.stuff"/> 
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed Hibernate and Spring configurations. They are completelly separate. You can't use Spring beans inside Hibernate config.

This will need to go to your Spring config:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource">
   <ref bean="dataSource"/>
</property>    
  <!-- SQL dialect -->
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
  <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="transaction.factory_class">
   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
  </property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">
  thread
  </property>
</bean>
```

I may be mistaken over small things since I usually use annotations configuration but you should go back to documentation.